# Why am I getting an HsqlException in my local TomEE 1.6?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hsqldb, apache-tomee

org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: ENRG

enrg is a table name. It is in the database and I am connecting as root. So this error message is misleading to say the least. Since my application is using Hibernate jars, I don't even understand why I'm seeing this. Based on what I've found on Web, it may be some misconfiguration of my local TomEE 1.6 that starts within Eclipse. Still, I have not figured out how to go about it.

Just to prove it's not an sql or permissions issue:
This code fails with above mentioned exception:

```
Query q=entityManager.createNativeQuery("insert into enrg values (null, 'ws', null, 'test', 'notes');");
q.executeUpdate();
```

I copy this insert and paste it into MySQL command line client and it works fine. Login credentials in both cases are identical (root/root).

The exception sits in this jar: c:\tomee16\lib\sqldb-2.3.0.jar

I'm using JPA 2.0 with Hibernate 4.

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
         version="2.0">

<persistence-unit name="default" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>my classess</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>


    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname?useUnicode=yes&amp;characterEncoding=utf8;" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root" />

        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
    </properties>

    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

**Update**

`Query q=entityManager.createNativeQuery("show tables;");` causes `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: SHOW`. My application does not know it's talking to a MySQL database.

Also, when starting up, here's a couple of warnings:
WARNING: jar 'C:\javawork\webadmin.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\WebAdmin\WEB-INF\lib\hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar' contains offending class: javax.persistence.Entity. It will be ignored.
WARNING: jar 'C:\javawork\webadmin.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\WebAdmin\WEB-INF\lib\jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar' contains offending class: javax.transaction.Transaction. It will be ignored.
Dec 07, 2013 1:22:37 AM org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory configureApplication

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the application never connected to the database. A datasource added to tomee.xml with server location change made it possible to establish a connection.

More here: [How to verify entity manager can establish a connection to the database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20445009/how-to-verify-entity-manager-can-establish-a-connection-to-the-database)